# Cannot access a div content when webscraping with selenium

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, selenium

I am learning web scraping and tried to build a script by using selenium & bs4 which scrapes data from aliexpress products. Example product using - https://www.aliexpress.com/item/33046358386.html

Trying to scrape product details with

```
details = soup.find("div", {"class": "product-detail-tab"})
```

but it returns only

```
<div class="product-detail-tab">
    <div class="lazyload-placeholder" style="height: 1000px;"></div>
</div>
```

even if I see on the webpage by inspecting that there is way more code.

Tried to find div in this way but it didn't change the result

```
details = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="product-detail-tab"]')
```

My full scraping code:

```
import pandas
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

product_id = "33046358386"

page_url = f"https://www.aliexpress.com/item/{product_id}.html"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/bin/chromedriver')
browser.get(page_url)
page_html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, 'html.parser');

product_name = soup.find("h1", {"class": "product-title-text"}).text.strip()
product_price = soup.find("span", {"class": "product-price-value"}).text.strip()
shipping_price = soup.find("div", {"class": "product-shipping-price"}).span.text.strip()
details = soup.find("div", {"class": "product-detail-tab"})

print(product_name)
print(product_price)
print(shipping_price)
print(description)

browser.close()
```

Would be thankful to hear what is the problem here.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: That is because as the class of the inner element suggests, that content is dynamically loaded later. After you get the page URL, you should wait until the element you want exists (something within `product-detail`tab` that takes a while to load). Then get the page source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sri pointed it out, you process the html without giving the dynamically loaded element time to get processed (there seems to be an API call in the background by the way - probably better than going selenium). I guess the proper way to handle it would something like this

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
...

browser.get(page_url)
MAX_WAIT_TIME = 60
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, MAX_WAIT_TIME)
element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.product-info")))
page_html = browser.page_source
```

And you could catch some TimeoutException in case it fail for some reason but it requires some more refactoring.

Comment: This helped me. Thanks!
But I guess you forgot 1 import:
"from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By"
Otherwise "By." will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't comment, I don't have enough rep. I'm still new to this stuff but I think I can point you in the right direction. Sri is correct that it's due to dynamic loading. If it's loaded with JavaScript, which seems to be the case here, you can use selenium with PhantomJS to get the source. Check out an example below.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://www.aliexpress.com/item/33046358386.html"
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
browser.get(url)
html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
a = soup.find('section', 'wrapper')
```